# Confusion about injective, surjective, bijective

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

As an example, I'm looking at $\sqrt{-x}$ for real $x.$ It's defined on the interval $(-\infty,0]$ and its inverse is defined on the interval $[0,\infty).$

Over which interval is this function injective, surjective and bijective?

If the domain is $(-\infty,0]$ then over this interval, it is injective because every real number in $(\infty,0]$ is mapped to at most one element in $\mathbb{R}$?

I'm confused about where this function is surjective, and if it's bijective at all.

The domain of this function's inverse is $[0,\infty).$ Does that mean the function is invertible over $[0,\infty)$?

Comment: I think you need more information (the image/range specified not just the domain) to give a 100% accurate answer to this exercise. If you know function $f: A \rightarrow B$ has an inverse $g : B \rightarrow A$ then necessarily it must be a bijection, because you have a one to one correspondence for every element in $A,B$ ($f$ is a function so everything is mapped once, $g$ is a function so everything is mapped back once). The point of the exercise might be to get you to think "yes there's an inverse but doesn't exist everywhere on certain sets", or to worry about $\pm$ square roots.

Comment: For this specific example with this specific domain being $(-\infty,0]$ and codomain being $[0,\infty)$, yes the function will be bijective.  As for showing it is surjective you need to show that every real number in the codomain is mapped to by *at least* one element of the domain.  Here, note that $y = \sqrt{-(-(y)^2)}=f(-(y^2))$ If the codomain was intended to be all of $\Bbb R$, then no it is not surjective.

Comment: @TheoDiamantakis My confusion is over which domain the function is invertible. $\sqrt{-x}$ does not exist over the interval $[0,\infty),$ but a function which effectively acts as its inverse does, being $-x^2,$ so is the original function $\sqrt{-x}$ invertible over $[0,\infty)$ or over $(-\infty,0]$? The original function does not exist over $[0,\infty)$ so this is confusing.

Comment: The interval $(\infty,0]$ is empty, you probably meant $(-\infty,0]$

Comment: Certainly if a function does not exist it cannot be invertible. The function $-x^2 :  (-\infty, 0] \rightarrow  (-\infty, 0]$ can be said to have inverse $\sqrt{-x}$ but changing the domain and ranges will either give you nonsense or lose the injective or surjective properties. As you can see, when both the domain and range are specified the question becomes a lot less ambiguous and its easier to give a comprehensive answer.

Comment: Is $\sqrt{-x}$ invertible over $(-\infty,0]$ since it exists over that interval? Or, is it invertible over $[0,\infty)$ since its inverse exists over that interval?

Answer (score 3):

1. You're correct that it's injective but your justification is hazy. It is injective because every real in $(-\infty,0]$, the domain, is mapped to a point in the codomain $[0,\infty)$ that is **unique** to the input (read: no two distinct elements of the domain are mapped to the same element in the codomain). You wrote: "It is mapped to *at most one* ..." but *any function whatsoever* will map elements in the domain to *exactly* one element in the codomain.
2. The function has an inverse, so it is indeed invertible. It's not clear what: 'over' should mean. If you have a function $f:X\to X$ that is invertible, it makes sense to say it is invertible over $X$. But the codomain is not equal to the domain, be careful; it is invertible as a function between $(-\infty,0]$ and $[0,\infty)$.

The function surjects onto the given codomain, because if you give me $y\in[0,\infty)$ I can create $x:=-y^2$, such that $\sqrt{-x}=y$.

Comment: The interval $(\infty,0]$ is empty, you probably meant $(-\infty,0]$.

Comment: @jjagmath Yes, fixed

Answer (score 0):

The function $y=\sqrt{-x}$ is defined, as you rightly say, on the domain $\{x\leq0\}$  and takes values in $\{x\geq0\}$ because square roots are always non-negative by convention.

Now note that you can define on $\{x\geq0\}$ the function $x=-y^2$ and observe that the two functions are inverse of each other. Indeed their domains/codomains are interchanged and
$$
-(\sqrt{-x})^2=-x\qquad \sqrt{-(-y^2)}=y.
$$
Thus *both* functions must be bijective (i.e. injective *and* surjective) since being invertible and being bijective are equivalent conditions.